# loop a list twice to find a second index and first index of the first loop and second loop

Tags: python

I want to loop a list twice.

- 1st will loop from index 0 - last
- second will loop from index 1 - last then back to 0 and stop.

I thought about using modulus but do not know how to start.

Can anyone please share?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is what I wish to get

```
loop 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
loop 2: 2,3,4,5,1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop by index and plus the number of loop, then mod the total length of the list to keep the index in range.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
length = len(lst)
loop_time = 2
for l in range(loop_time):
    for ind in range(length):
        print(lst[(ind + l) % length])
```

Comment: Wow! this is what I wanted it to be. thank you. I am sorry for not including my codes, I was kinda hurry so I didnt include it and Im ok with getting downvoted. thank you so much.